# How to tell forfiles to execute command in PATH?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I'm missing something (obvious?) about escaping my strings or spaces in the following Windows Server 2k3 batch command.

```
FORFILES -m *.wsp -c "CMD /C C:\Program^ Files\Common^ Files\Microsoft^ Shared\web^ server^ extensions\12\bin\stsadm.exe^ -o^ addsolution^ -filename^ @FILE"
```

Results in the following error

```
'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\bin\stsadm.exe -o addsolution -filename "foobar.wsp"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

But I can't figure out why. I'm working off [Mr. Simon Sheppard's fine documentation](http://www.ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)

Comment: Closely related: [How do you run a command with a full path from the Windows forfiles command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39452239)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The path needs to be quoted, and the quote must be escaped.

```
FORFILES -m *.wsp -c "CMD /C ^0x22C:\Program^ Files\Common^ Files\Microsoft^ Shared\web^ server^ extensions\12\bin\stsadm.exe^0x22 -o^ addsolution^ -filename^ @FILE"
```

A co-worker suggested using the hex for ", and I eventually figured out that the hex needed escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer is to use the old 8.3 names you get by doing dir /X.

Like:  C:\PROGRA~1 instead of C:\Program Files.