# Forfiles - spaces in folder path

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I am running a batch file and I have one forfiles command in it

```
FORFILES -p%spinputarchrootpath% -m*.csv -d-365 -c"CMD /C DEL @FILE"

%spinputarchrootpath% variable maps to a folder location (Y:\Temp Documents\testfolder).
```

Now the above command is throwing an error because of the space in the folder name (Temp Documents).

How to handle this space? I have tried putting quotes around `%spinputarchrootpath%` variable but it is not working.

Answer (score 7):

I'd the same problem and found the solution.
I think your folder-variable of the folder you wish to empty has a backslash at the end.

This will NOT work:

echo J|forfiles /P "**C:\temp files\**" /S /M * /D -7 /C "cmd /c del /F /S /Q @path"

... but this works (without backslash)

echo J|forfiles /P "**C:\temp files**" /S /M * /D -7 /C "cmd /c del /F /S /Q @path"

Regards

Tino

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the path in quotes:

```
FORFILES -p "%spinputarchrootpath%" -m *.csv -d -365 -c "CMD /C DEL @FILE"
```

Note, there's a space between `-p` and `"%spinputarchrootpath%"`. Without a space in this case it won't work.

Comment: @Sahil: I don't know why I didn't pay attention initially, but now I see that you didn't put spaces after other parameters too. And I didn't either, but now I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around first change directories to the folder you want, and then execute forfiles without the /p parameter.

```
CD %spinputarchrootpath%
FORFILES -m*.csv -d-365 -c"CMD /C DEL @FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check post:
[How to Tell FORFILES to Execute Command on Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508779/how-to-tell-forfiles-to-execute-command-on-path)

The problem lies in the part:
-c"CMD /C DEL @FILE"

Use:
-c"CMD /C DEL ^0x22@FILE^0x22"
to put extra double quotes around the file