# Using FORFILES to pass files to program

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf

I'm trying to write a 2 line .bat file in Windows 7 to search recursively in the root folder and subfolders for pdfs and print them however the `FORFILES` command as in my file:

```
set fxread="C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe"
forfiles /s /m *.pdf /c "%fxread% /p @FILE"
```

Gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'Files'.
```

However if I just use `FORFILES` to echo the filename I get as expected a list of pdf files; i.e this code:

```
forfiles /s /m *.pdf /c "cmd /c echo @FILE"
```

Produces a list of pdf files, one per line and encased in quotation marks.

Anyone know why I can't pass these files to the PDF viewer for printing? Note that this command does print a pdf file as expected:

```
%fxread% /p "FILE_NAME.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrap a string in quotes to preserve the spaces, the quotes become part of the string. Combine that with the quotes required by forfiles, and you're passing the command `forfiles /s /m *.pdf /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /p @FILE"`

Place the first quote before fxread to avoid including quotes in the string. Additionally, spaces, parentheses, and the hex equivalents of quotes need to be escaped.

```
set "fxread=^0x22C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\Foxit^ Software\Foxit^ Reader\Foxit^ Reader.exe^0x22^ /p"
forfiles /s /m *.pdf /c "cmd /c %fxread% @path"
```

Comment: Roger that about the quotes - I've looked at your post and mine and am having a blind minute where I can

Comment: Roger that about the quotes - I'm having a blind moment now and can't spot the difference between mine and your command but I've tried your fix and now just get `ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.` - again something to do with the output of `FORFILES` having quotes?

Comment: I forgot that system commands indicated by `/c` should be preceded by `cmd /c`. I've edited my code above.

Comment: And Windows, god bless it, now tells me it cannot find 'C:\Program' so it looks to me like the quotes which were breaking the command are necessary to not break the command *bashes head on wall*

Comment: I finally found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/508937/4158862) which indicated that I needed to escape some characters in order for it to work.

Comment: Problem solved - wow that was unexpectedly complicated. I cannot understand how a human being is expected to use the hex code for the quotation mark! You amaze me and your help is much appreciated SomethingDark.